# React JS TypeError: props.cartProductsArr is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having a TypeError when I try to map through the cart of products and display it in a modal.
I'm using redux to store my states and access them from other components.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the Card component from where I send the product to the cart state:

```
 const ProductCard = (props) => {
    const product = props.product
    return (
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-6">
            <div className="product-top">
                <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />

                <div className="product-bottom">
                    <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                    <p>{`${product.price} MT`}</p>
                </div>
                <button className="btn add-cart-btn" onClick={() => props.addProductsToCart(product)}>Adicionar ao carrinho</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        addProductsToCart: product => dispatch(addCartProducts(product))
    })
    
    export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductCard);
```

This is the component where I access the name and price of the cart product:

```
const CartProduct = (props) => {
const { name, price } = props.product;
return (
    <div>
        <span>{name}</span>
        <span>{price}</span>
    </div>
)
}
export default CartProduct;
```

This is the component where I map the cart products array and set the id and the product itself:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CartProduct from './CartProduct';

import '../../styles/_cart-dropdown.scss';
import { setCartModalStatus } from '../../redux/status/status.action';


const CartModal = (props) => {
    const status = props.cartModalStatus;

    return (
        <Modal
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
            show={status}
            onHide={props.setCartModalStatus}
        >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                    Modal heading
                </Modal.Title>
                <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                    Modal heading
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                    **{
                        props.cartProductsArr.map(cartProduct => {
                            return <CartProduct key={cartProduct._id} product={cartProduct}/>
                        })
                    }**
            </Modal.Body>
             

        </Modal>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    cartModalStatus: state.status.cartmodal,
    cartProductsArr: state.cart.cartProducts
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setCartModalStatus: () => dispatch(setCartModalStatus())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartModal);
```

Comment: Is what is in the title the exact error message?

Comment: Sorry to avoid confusion i edited the title. Now is the actual error. Thnks :)

Comment: you're not calling props.cartProductsArr as a function, Assuming you mean the error is props.cartProductsArr.map is not a function? which would mean that cartProductsArr is not an array, pretty hard to see what's going on without knowing how you're getting the cartProducts in your state

Comment: @RyanWolton , I'm getting it from redux state, which the initial state is an empty array

Comment: I would suggest a console.log(props.cartProductsArr) to see what you're getting

Comment: @RyanWolton, I'm getting the cartProductsArr with the product

Comment: The problem is when I try to map through it. I don't get why this is happening

Comment: Can you paste the output here?

Comment: `brand: "Samsung", createdAt: "2021-03-23T10:47:48.223Z"
image: "http://localhost:3000/uploads/1616496468213-Samsung-Smart-TV.png"
images: []
isFeatured: false
name: "SAMSUNG 65" Class 4K Ultra HD (2160P) HDR Smart QLED TV QN65Q60TB"
numReviews: 0
price: 50000
rating: 0
richDescription: ""
updatedAt: "2021-03-23T10:47:48.223Z"
__v: 0
_id: "6059c7540ca1a81ab07dc926"
__proto__: Object
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cartProductsArr is an object and not an array. In your mapStateToProps, from the naming I would guess that state.cart could be your array. I would console.log your state in your mapState just to know exactly everything being passed.

Comment: That is 100% correct, I just fixed it by returning an array of objects and filter by _id those with the same ids and return an array of the objects. Thanks. Take care, peace and love  : )